# Calculating multiple elements' position in order to .offset() it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, offset

## Where I'm At

I've managed to get the location of all of the headshots of politicans in `index.html` using jQuery's .offset()

## Where I'm Stuck

I'm looking to get each individual image's location on the page (using their class or id) and then change the current top and left values of the tooltip (which contains info about each of the politicians), using .offset() so it's appears near/above where the corresponding image of that politician is on the page.

## UPDATE #1

**@Roko:** Can you elaborate on why the positioning needs to be fixed in this case. Likewise, with your suggested change, I can see the HTML for `div class="tooltip" style="display: block; top: ... px; left ... px;"></div>` but the numbers seem to have shifted the tooltip too much.

### Tried:

```
    $('img').each(function(){
        var img = $(this);

        img.click(function(){
                 $('.tooltip')
                 .show(100)
                 .text(img.attr('alt'))
                 .offset({
                    top : img.offset().top + img.height(),
                    left : img.offset().left
            });
        });



    });
```

**AND**

```
var   position = $el.data('.elem'),
                ImagePosition = $el.offset(),
                ImageSize = {
                  'width': $el.outerWidth(),
                  'height': $el.outerHeight()
                };

        'top': ImagePosition.top - el.outerHeight() 
        'left': ImagePosition.left - (elelment.outerWidth()/2) + (elementSize.width/2)
```

### scripts.js

```
    // Positioning of the tooltips
    $(".headshot").click(function(){

        // Fades in the tooltip
        $(".tooltip").fadeIn("fast");

        // This is the coordinates for current position of a tooltip
        var coords = $(".tooltip").offset();

        var height = $(".tooltip").height();
        console.log(height);

        var width = $(".tooltip").width();
        console.log(width);

        // How do I figure out how much top or left I need to move it?
        alert("Top: " + coords.top + " Left: " + coords.left);
        console.log(coords);
});
```

### index.html

```
<div class="tooltip">
                <div class="info">
                    <p class="tooltipName"></p>
                    <p class="tooltipParty"></p> <p class="tooltipConstuency"></p>
                    <p class="tooltipEthnicity"></p> <p class="tooltipAge"></p>
                    </div><!-- /.info -->

                    <div class="arrow-down">
                    </div><!-- /.arrow-down -->
                </div><!-- /.tooltip -->

<img src="assets/img/headshots/allan.jpg" alt="" id="0" class="headshot NDP Female White">
                <img src="assets/img/headshots/allum.jpg" alt="" id="1" class="headshot NDP Male White">
                <img src="assets/img/headshots/altemeyer.jpg" alt="" id="2" class="headshot NDP Male White">
```

### tooltip.scss

```
/*----------------------------------
TOOLTIP
----------------------------------*/

.tooltip {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    left: -12px;
    top: -5px;
}

.info {
    @include serifLight;
    background: $yellow;
    color: $black;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 9%;
    text-align: center;

    p {
        margin: 0px;
    }
}

.tooltipName, {
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab',serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.tooltipEthnicity, .tooltipAge {
    display: inline;
}

.arrow-down {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
```

Comment: I can't see the link to the JS Fiddle...

Comment: @JamesBlond a link to jsFiddle is not needed when the code is all there.

Comment: Maybe, but she writes in the question: 'Here's a link to a JSFiddle: ' and then there's no link. So she probably forgot to paste it in...

Comment: @JamesBlond The code is all there, like Roko said, there was really no need for a JSFiddle

Comment: For the a clear outline and updates to the question +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/yuzeli/3/edit?html,css,js,output)***

```
$('img').click(function(){

    var img = $(this);

    $('.tooltip')
    .show(100)
    .text( this.alt )
    .css({
        top : img.offset().top + img.height(),
        left : img.offset().left
    });

});
```

and

```
.tooltip {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;  /* set to absolute */
    left: -12px;
    top: -5px;
}
```

also make sure to actually have some value inside the `alt=""` attribute!

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the positioning needs to be fixed in this case. Likewise, with your suggested change, I can see the HTML for `div class="tooltip" style="display: block; top: ... px; left ... px;"></div>` but the numbers seem to have shifted the tooltip too much.

Comment: @MaryYacoubian it depends where are yoru tooltip and the images exactly inside your HTML. If tooltip element and images are inside the same parent than you can also set to `absolute`

Comment: @MaryYacoubian please don't post comments in your question. Use this comment section. I've updated my answer using `absolute`. See if it works.

Comment: Adding a value inside my "alt" attribute doesn't really solve my problem as it just creates text next to one of the images, where I actually want to be moving the `div.tooltip` by .offset() it's top and left values.

Comment: Absolute positioning gives the same result as fixed positioning in this case.

Comment: @MaryYacoubian can you please create a jsBin demo with your issue? Here is mine and it works: http://jsbin.com/yuzeli/4/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: It works. I just need to fix the width of the tooltips now. Thanks!